# Rust DataFusion - Float Operations in dataframe select

Tags: rust, apache-arrow

I am calculating fraction of orders that were not filled from a large list of order lines. I am using datafusion crate to perform analysis. I want to build a table that looks as shown below:

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| Month  | Total Orders | Missed Orders | Missed Ratio |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| 201803 | 10           | 3             | 0.3          |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

To achieve this I have return following code:

```
    let result = record_count
        .select(vec![col("Month"), 
            col("Total Orders"), 
            col("Missed Orders"),
            (col("Missed Orders").cast_to(&DataType::Float64, &m_order_schema).unwrap() / col("Total Orders").cast_to(&DataType::Float64, &t_order_schema).unwrap()).alias("Service Level")])?;
```

The total orders and missed orders column as integers so, I am casting them to float to get fraction. But, Service Level column comes out as integer with all zeros. Result looks as shown below:

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| Month  | Total Orders | Missed Orders | Missed Ratio |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| 201803 | 10           | 3             | 0            |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Question: How to perform float operations with integer columns?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think many people are monitoring stack overflow for DataFusion issues and you might get a quicker response by filing an issue at https://github.com/apache/arrow-datafusion/issues

Comment: Thanks Andy. Posted the same to github. I posted it here as there was no standard template for queries in the project issues. I felt maybe it would be out of place there.